# Tabela com tamanho variável em HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Preciso que uma tabela em HTML seja alimentada por um banco de dados mas a quantidade de dados é variável. A quantidade de colunas é fixa porém a quantidade de linhas pode variar. É necessário que a tabela se adeque ao volume de dados fornecidos pelo banco de dados. O usuário apenas seleciona de qual empresa ele quer os dados, e a tabela é criada e preenchida de acordo com a escolha.

Comment: Qual o problema? Só adicionar um novo `<tr>` e os seus `<td>` para cada campo

Comment: Todo mês a quantidade de dados vai variar, preciso que seja automatizado.

Comment: Como pode ver na resposta, o trabalho para escrever duas linhas é o mesmo para escrever 100000 de linhas na tabela. Não entendi a dificuldade ainda

Comment: Porém eu editar o código todo mês não é automatização, não tenho como alterar todo arquivo que crio por que entrou dados novos, entende?

Comment: Você está usando duas tags de linguagem próprias para servir páginas dinâmicas/linguagens da web 2.0. Se você só serve páginas estáticas, então você deveria automatizar a escrita dessa página estática. Então, qual sua dificuldade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando os poucos dados que tu forneceste, acredito que sua solução seja algo semelhante a isto:

```
<?php
$con = new PDO("mysql: host=localhost;dbname=stackoverflow;charset=utf8", "root", "");
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );


$stmt = $con->prepare("select * from dados where empresa = ?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $_GET['empresa']);
$stmt->execute();
 $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll();

?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Dado1</th>
            <th>Dado2</th>
            <th>Dado3</th>
        </tr>
    </head>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach($resultado as $dados)
            {
                echo
                '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$dados->dado1.'</td>
                    <td>'.$dados->dado2.'</td>
                    <td>'.$dados->dado3.'</td>
                </tr>
                ';
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Agora, se você deseja que apenas mostre parte do resultado e quando o usuário aperte em um link ou botão mostre outra parte, na sua query será necessário o uso de OFFSET e LIMIT e aprender a fazer paginação. Como por exemplo:

```
select * from dados where empresa = ? limit 3 offset 5
```

Neste caso essa query vai selecionar no máximo 3 linhas a partir da sexta linha.

Comment: Quando se há pouca informação, o ideal é através de comentários ir perguntando ao **AP** a dúvida ou problema que o mesmo esteja enfrentando, até que se esclareça, também muita das vezes o mesmo tem que adicionar um [**MCVE**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).